# Z transform (transform function and impulse response)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, laplace-transform, closed-form

How to calculate and plot the impulse response?
$$y[n]-y[n-1]+0.9y[n-2]=x[n]$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One has
$$
Y(z)-z^{-1}Y(z)+0.9z^{-2}Y(z)=X(z)
$$ giving
$$
\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=H(z)=\frac1{1-z^{-1}+0.9z^{-2}}=1+\frac{z-0.9}{z^2-z+0.9}
$$ then one may use a [table of Laplace and Z transforms](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html) to conclude.